# Return value is not shown

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I want output to be shown as "10" but below code outputs "`System.Func'1[System.Int32]`"

Doesn't function return "10" ? Why is this not displayed?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        public int Get10()
        {
            return 10;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ten=new Func<int>(new Program().Get10);            
            Console.WriteLine(ten);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are encapsulating the method when you declared it as `Func`, when you call `ten`, it is not yet invoked.

In order to execute it, you must use `.Invoke()`

`Console.WriteLine(ten.Invoke());`

Or use delegate instance

`Console.WriteLine(ten());`

https://dotnetfiddle.net/d2mPPz

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Console.WriteLine(ten()):
```

You are printing the string representation of the `Func` object.
But you have to invoke it using `()`

Answer (score 2):

Ten is a Func, so if you want to see "10", you need to invoke it like **ten.Invoke()**